# Rails global style configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My application is geared towards educational institutions and my goal is to let them style their site with their school colors if they do not like the original ones.

How can I create a stylesheet that can be edited in Rails? Would this be best stored in a database or something like the `production.rb` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you, I would add column `color` to table `schools`. On the views, I would use dynamic class color that was based on current school. Eg:

```
## views
<div class="container #{school_color_class(@school)}">
  <h3>Example</h3>
</div>

## helpers
def school_color_class(school)
  return 'bg-primary' if school.color.blank?

  "bg-#{school.color}"
end
```